# Why do I need to install redux along with react-redux?

Tags: npm, redux, react-redux

If `react-redux` depends on redux and can't function without it, why would `redux` not be part of `react-redux` library?
Is it only because someone may want to uninstall `react-redux` and still want to keep with `redux` in a react project?
 Or is there some other logic?

Answer (score 1):

Because Redux is a standalone JS library that can be used with any UI framework (React, Angular, Vue) or even vanilla JS / jQuery.  React-Redux is the specific bindings library that lets your React components interact with the Redux store, and there are bindings libraries for other UI layers as well.  So, there are separate but related libraries that do different jobs.

Please see my post [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) and my talk [A Deep Dive into React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/06/presentation-react-redux-deep-dive/) for more details on what React-Redux does and how it works.